Sonar scanner analysis is failing with ADO task version 6
We are trying to run Sonar scan with latest ADO task version v6 and it is failing with the following error. Sonar scan works with ADO task version v5.
/azp/_work/_tasks/SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055/6.3.2/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner
11:25:43.109 INFO  Scanner configuration file: /azp/_work/_tasks/SonarQubeAnalyze_6d01813a-9589-4b15-8491-8164aeb38055/6.3.2/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
11:25:43.116 INFO  Project root configuration file: NONE
11:25:43.147 INFO  SonarScanner CLI 6.1.0.4477
11:25:43.149 INFO  Java 17.0.12 Ubuntu (64-bit)
11:25:43.150 INFO  Linux 5.4.0-189-generic amd64
11:25:43.160 DEBUG Scanner max available memory: 15 GB
11:25:43.200 DEBUG uname -m returned 'x86_64'
11:25:43.202 DEBUG Create: /home/agent/.sonar/cache
11:25:43.203 INFO  User cache: /home/agent/.sonar/cache
11:25:43.204 DEBUG Create: /home/agent/.sonar/cache/_tmp
11:25:43.553 DEBUG Loaded [415] system trusted certificates
11:25:43.828 DEBUG --> GET https://sonarprod.cloud.aero/api/v2/analysis/version
11:25:44.010 DEBUG <-- 200 https://sonarprod.cloud.aero/api/v2/analysis/version (182ms, 12-byte body)
11:25:44.013 INFO  JRE provisioning: os[linux], arch[x86_64]
11:25:44.017 DEBUG --> GET https://sonarprod.cloud.aero/api/v2/analysis/jres?os=linux&arch=x86_64
11:25:44.025 DEBUG <-- 200 https://sonarprod.cloud.aero/api/v2/analysis/jres?os=linux&arch=x86_64 (8ms, unknown-length body)
11:25:44.926 INFO  EXECUTION FAILURE
11:25:44.927 INFO  Total time: 1.870s
##[error]11:25:44.928 ERROR Error during SonarScanner CLI execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to extract archive
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.lib.internal.JavaRunnerFactory.extractArchive(JavaRunnerFactory.java:200)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.lib.internal.JavaRunnerFactory.getJreFromServer(JavaRunnerFactory.java:145)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.lib.internal.JavaRunnerFactory.createRunner(JavaRunnerFactory.java:85)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.lib.internal.ScannerEngineLauncherFactory.createLauncher(ScannerEngineLauncherFactory.java:53)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.lib.ScannerEngineBootstrapper.bootstrap(ScannerEngineBootstrapper.java:118)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.analyze(Main.java:75)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:63)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/agent/.sonar/cache/bcb1b7b8ad68c93093f09b591b7cb17161d39891f7d29d33a586f5a328603707/jre8181025238927046063/jdk-17.0.11+9-jre/lib/server/classes.jsa


Could you please share the details of your pipeline?



task: SonarQubePrepare@6
inputs:
SonarQube: 'SonarQubeServiceConnection'
scannerMode: 'CLI'
configMode: 'file'
configFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/sonar-project.properties'
extraProperties:
sonar.verbose=true
- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@6
  displayName: "Running SonarScan"




Please edit your question and paste the code there - it's really difficult to read the code sample in the comments. Thanks!

Upon checking this link, it seems that not only SonarQubeAnalyze@6 task but also SonarCloudAnalyze@2 task may incur this issue Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/azagent/.sonar/cache/bcb1b7b8ad68c93093f09b591b7cb17161d39891f7d29d33a586f5a328603707/jre1162657528265033278/jdk-17.0.11+9-jre/lib/server/classes.jsa and those tasks @ old version are working.
Since the marketplace extensions are published by SonarSource, you may visit the publisher's support page to seek further fix by their maintainers.
